# Is $G=\langle g,h:g^{2p}=h^2=1,g^h=g^{-1}\rangle$ for $|G|=\text{ord }g\cdot\text{ord }h$ a valid group presentation?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $4p$ where $p\ge 5$ is any odd prime number and $\sigma,\tau\in G$ with $\text{ord }\sigma =2p$, $\text{ord }\tau=2$ and $\sigma^\tau :=\tau\sigma \tau ^{-1}=\sigma^{-1}$. Is $$G=\langle\sigma,\tau : \sigma^{2p}=\tau^2=1,\sigma^\tau =\sigma^{-1}\rangle$$ a valid group presentation?

In other words: Can we conclude from the given facts that $G$ has such a presentation?

Comment: Yes, it's the standard presentation of the dihedral group.

Comment: @DerekHolt - So, we can state $$G\cong D_{4p}$$ only knowing that $G$ contains an element $\sigma$ of order $2p$ and an element $\tau$ of order $2$ and their is a relation $\sigma^\tau =\sigma^{-1}$ between them?

Comment: @DerekHolt - Maybe, my question was not precisely enough. I want to know if we can conclude from the given facts that $G$ has such a presentation.

Comment: The answer is still yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the given condition, we at least know that $G$ is a *quotient* of th epresented group.
Remains to show that the presented group has no more than $4p$ elements. To do so you might show (by induction)  that all elements of the presented group can be written as $\sigma^i\tau^j$ with $0\le i<2p$, $0\le j<2$.

Comment: Isn't it clear from the definition of a group presentation that each element of the presented group can be written in such a way?

Comment: @0xbadf00d. Use that to=o^{-1}t to flip products.